# How to test if a nested Python list contains a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list of Python strings, like this one:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

I would like to quickly test if a given string is equal to any of the strings in any of the sublists. I could write a function to flatten the list, but the test needs to happen in a time-critical portion of my program. Is there a faster or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Iterate over the lists?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Should I delete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't avoid having to loop and scan through elements here; but you can at least avoid having to scan all lists, and delegate the task of scanning each sublist to Python C code.

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test each sublist in a generator expression:

```
any(search in sublist for sublist in l)
```

`any()` will stop iterating over the generator expression the moment if finds a `True` value (e.g. when `search in sublist` found a match).

Comment: This is the best solution because it short-circuits. It will at worst be O(N), but it must be by definition of the problem. At best you will hit the short circuit and bail earlier.